# Export data from HTML-Form to JSON-File

Tags: javascript, html, json

I know how to make a JSON object and put it in the file. But I don't want to delete the upper part "general" when inserting the data. How do I do this?

I want to make one file since it's better to read only one file instead of multiple files in an other instance of the program in this particular case.

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="team-1-name">Team 1</td>
      <td id="team-2-name">Team 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TeamID:</td>
      <td><input id="teamid-1" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
      <td><input id="teamid-2" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Teamname:</td>
      <td><input id="teamname-1" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
      <td><input id="teamname-2" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Teamabbreviation:</td>
      <td><input id="teamabbr-1" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
      <td><input id="teamabbr-2" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Save Settings" />
</form>
```

and I want to save the data in a JSON file.

```json
{
  "general": {
    "some": null,
    "other": null,
    "data": null
  },
  "teams": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "abbr": "",
      "id": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "abbr": "",
      "id": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you. Please click [edit] and add your attempts to the snippet created for you so we have a [mcve]

Comment: You read the existing file content and _decode_ it first; then you manipulate the resulting data structure, and then you encode the modified data structure as JSON again.

Comment: This would also be my solution. Im just curious if there is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. load the JSON and use `JSON.parse()` to parse it to a normal JS object.
2. print your table with the data object.
3. use a `for` loop to create an array of the team data.
4. push the `teams` array into the data object replacing the old one
5. `stringify()` the data back to a JSON

Note that I replace your IDs to utilize `data` attributes for simplicity.

```js
const BUTTON = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');
let dataObject;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  dataObject = JSON.parse(`
    {"general": {
      "some":null,
      "other":null,
      "data":null
    },
    "teams": [
      {
        "name": "no data",
        "abbr": "no data",
        "id": "no data"
      },
      {
        "name": "no data",
        "abbr": "no data",
        "id": "no data"
      }
    ]
  }`);
  
  // function to print the table
});

BUTTON.addEventListener('click', constructor);

function constructor() {
  let numberOfTeams = document.querySelectorAll('table tr:nth-child(1) td').length - 1; 
  dataObject.teams = saveTeamData(numberOfTeams)
  
  console.log(createJSON(dataObject));
}

function saveTeamData(numberOfTeams) {
  let teams = [];
  for (index = 1; index <= numberOfTeams; index++) {
    let teamObject = {
      name: document.querySelector(`[data-teamname="${index}"]`).value,
      abbr: document.querySelector(`[data-teamabbr="${index}"]`).value,
      id: document.querySelector(`[data-teamid="${index}"]`).value,
    };
    
    teams.push(teamObject);
  }
  
  return teams;
}

function createJSON(dataObject) {
  return JSON.stringify(dataObject);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="team-1-name">Team 1</td>
      <td id="team-2-name">Team 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="TeamID">
      <th>TeamID:</th>
      <td><input data-teamid="1" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
      <td><input data-teamid="2" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-header="TeamName">
      <th>Teamname:</th>
      <td><input data-teamname="1" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
      <td><input data-teamname="2" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr  data-header="TeamAbbr">
      <th>Teamabbreviation:</th>
      <td><input data-teamabbr="1" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
      <td><input data-teamabbr="2" type="text" value="no data" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Save Settings" />
</form>
```